# Does the terminal learn common typos?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, alias, ls

This may seem like a stupid question.

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 with GNOME Terminal 3.16.2. When I was new to the system, I often typed 'l' or 'la' instead of 'ls' to list files, and would then be told that these were not valid commands. I obviously then typed 'ls' properly. Now I notice that typing 'l' and 'la' do the same thing as 'ls'.

What's going on here? Has the terminal learnt the common mistakes that I make, and made aliases to account for them, or is this a new feature that I've installed without realising?

Comment: Are they aliases? `type la` will help. Are they links? `/bin/ls -l $(type -p la )`. Some programs behave differently depending on the name (`argv[0]`).

Answer (score 1):

When you call `l` or `la`, you basically call aliases:

```
l='ls -lah'
la='ls -lAh'
```

You can check all aliases, currently configured in your system by running `alias`. It may be good to have some self-learining mechanism that will remember your typos an fix them, but for now it's just pre-configured aliases.

Related question on: [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109216/l-ls-la-what-are-the-differences-and-are-there-more-of-these-commands)

Answer (score 0):

Shell itself doesn't have capability to do spellchecking for the user. What you have with `la` and `l` is aliases. In the `.bashrc` file you can set alias for any command. For instance, if I often mistype `pwd` command to print working directory, I'd use this in my `.bashrc` file:

```
alias pdw='pwd'
```

The aliases `l` and `la` should exist in bash shell by default and I don't see a reason why they wouldn't work for you before. If you are a user on a machine who has a different administrator , then it's likely he or she disabled or enabled those.

There is `sl` command , which is not included by default in Ubuntu, but shows an animation of steam locomotive (hence `sl` name) when you mistype `ls`. This however is something that needs to be manually installed.

If a command is a complex combination of other commands, you could always use a function, like so

```
sl()
{
  echo "You've mistyped ls again"
  echo "Don't rush" 
}
```

If you are writing a script, you can sort of do spell checking (and much more)  on that using [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net/)